# Losing reputation for downvoting

Tags: support, lost-reputation

A few days ago, I downvoted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25237910/3576493) answer. Right after I downvoted, I was told that I had lost two reputation points/marks (whatever they're called).

I thought nothing of it until today, when I lost another reputation point because of it. What's going on? Is it a bug or can people be penalised for downvoting answers?

Comment: You lose one point for down-voting answers. If you lost two the someone else down-voted you.

Comment: @ChrisF I've downvoted answers before with no reputation loss though

Comment: That would only be the case if they were Community Wiki answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So a little about downvoting.

- Downvoting any questions costs no rep points.
- Downvoting usual answers costs you 1 rep.
- Downvoting answers, marked as [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) costs no rep points
- Downvoting any answers and questions on child metas (e.g. [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com))
  costs no rep points

If you didn't lose a rep point while downvoting an answer, it could be because it was on child meta or marked CW.

Answer (score 1):

If you downvote answers you lose 1 rep.  If you downvote questions, you lose no rep at all.

If that answer gets deleted, you get your 1 rep back.

I imagine that the purpose of this is to discourage vindictive downvote wars.

Comment: So the system still allows a bunch of trolls to gang up on you and downvote all the questions you ask, w/o being penalized.

Comment: @GeneB well, those trolls need to get 125 rep first to be able to DV.  But yes, sometimes users misbehave, unfortunately.  SE places high-enough value on questions that they decided to accept this cost.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, More than just "sometimes". In fact, many go off scot-free.